# ggplot2 use themes from R in python

Tags: python, ggplot2, themes

There are great packages for ggplot2 in R like https://github.com/cttobin/ggthemr to get awesome looking plots. Has someone parted them to the python edition https://github.com/yhat/ggpy of ggplot2?

What is needed to get these R themes to work in python?